# How can you use GWT AutoBeans to parse a JSON message when some of the return values could be an object or a collection of objects?

Tags: json, parsing, gwt, autobean

Is it possible to parse a JSON message using GWT AutoBeans when one of the objects returned may be a collection but not always?

For example, if I have a JSON message returning an author and his/her associated writings, it's possible that there could be zero or more books being returned.

```
{ "name" : "William Gibson", "books" : { bookname : "Neuromancer" } }
```

could be one response, but so could this:

```
{ "name" : "William Gibson", "books" : [ { bookname: "Neuromancer"}, { bookname : "Pattern Recognition" } ] }
```

When I attempt to model this with an interface to be used for marshalling with an AutoBean, I get "expecting indexed data" errors if only one book is returned.

Interface for the AutoBean:

```
public interface Author {
  @PropertyName(value="name")
  String getAuthorName();
  @PropertyName(value="book")
  List<String> getBooks();
}
```

Snippet of error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expecting indexed data
at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.SplittableList.<init>(SplittableList.java:64)
```

Is this not possible with AutoBeans?

(Note: using GWT 2.5.0 GA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `List`, AutoBeans expects a JSON array. That array could contain zero, one or more elements, but it has to be an array (or be absent).

I think you can make your `getBooks` method return a `Splittable` though. You could then know whether it's an array (`isIndexed()`) or not. If you need the array to contain objects, you'd then have to iterate on the array (`size()` and `get(int)`) and pass each element to `AutoBeanCodex.decode()` to decode them (or directly pass the splittable if it's not an array).

Comment: Ok but if I have no control over the JSON message itself (e.g. I cannot force it into an array format of n elements), is there no way to model the AutoBean in a way that it can handle when only one element is returned?

Comment: I think you could use a `Splittable` property type; see edited answer.